# How large is the market for anime & manga by each country?

Tags: merchandise, resources

I would like to know how large the anime and manga industry is in each country. I think US, Japan, and China are the three largest country for anime and manga, but want to know how big they are with the approximated figures.

I searched for it but couldn't get to it. Can I know maybe the top 10 rankings?

Comment: AFAIK Japan is first and France is second

Comment: [Related](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/which-countries-watch-the-most-anime)

Comment: @BrunoCosta Well, that's what I got to before posting the question.

Comment: @Ikaros Is this true of anime too? I'm sure that's the case in manga.

Comment: It is true for mangas, I do not know about animes